How to animate LazyList layout - replicate Recyclerview animation
Is it possible yet in Jetpack Compose to animate items in a LazyList when entering a page?
Expected result (the animation titled "Fall down")

Attempt before the Jetpack Compose era
fall_down.xml
<set xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>

    <alpha android:fromAlpha=”0”
         android:toAlpha=”1”
         android:duration=”300”/>
     
    <translate android:fromYdelta=”-200%”
        android:toYAlpha=”0%”
        android:duration=”300"/>
</set>

layout_animation
<layoutAnimation
    android:delay="15%"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:animation"@anim/fall_down"/>

activity_main.xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"/>
 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Current Jetpack Compose code in MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            FoodCategoriesScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FoodCategoriesScreen() {
    val items = listOf("Starters", "Mains", "Desserts")

    LazyColumn {
        items(items) { item ->
            Text(text = item, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        }
    }
}

